# All I need to know about image and video resolution, size and quality in my smartphone

Tags: video, images, screen-resolution

**About Images**

My android smartphone captures images of resolution 4160 x 3120 px (horizontally) with its 13 megapixel rear camera. The image size is usually around 5 MB which is obviously hard to upload on Internet and share it via Whatsapp especially if we talk about slow Internet connection. Moreover it consumes a lot of precious storage space in computer, mobile, SD card etc.

Therefore, I resize images of above resolution to 1366 x 1025 px in my computer using some image editing software. The resized image becomes of size around 400 KB which is very much smaller than that of original image. But will it reduce image quality as well?

Additionally I am wondering about one more thing - What If I shoot a picture initially with resolution 1366 x 1025 px? Will it's quality be the same to the computer resized version of bigger resolution image? To make you guys more clear, here it is:

```
Original (JPEG)         Resized (JPEG)     Quality                                      Size

4160 x 3120 px  =>      1366 x 1025 px      Low/High/Same?                              400 KB

1366 x 1025 px  =>      No Resize           Low/High/Same to above resized version?     ?
```

**About Video**

1. The 10 seconds duration video recorded in SD (720 x 480 px) format is around 3 MB.
2. The 10 seconds duration video recorded in HD (1280 x 720 px) format is around 18 MB.
3. The 10 seconds duration video recorded in Full HD (1920 x 1080 px) format is around 25 MB.
4. The 10 seconds duration video recorded in 4K (3840 x 2160 px) format is around 55 MB.

Same situation arises for uploading and sharing video over internet. Also the storage problem too. So if I compress 4K or Full HD video into HD format then will it reduce video quality? Also how much HD compressed version of 4K and Full HD formats will differ in terms of quality as compared to original HD version without any compression?

Comment: A really important factor in determining the file size is the format in which the image is saved (e.g. JPEG, PNG, BMP, RAW etc.). Can you please add the file formats to your table for both the images from your phone and the images after processing with your computer?

Comment: I think this is more likely to be well answered on [photography.se] than on here. But in short, the benefit of taking in higher resolution is that you have much more detail before it's resized (I'm not talking about compression, it's a different thing)

Comment: @famdekk, I updated my question. Picture file format is JPEG.

Comment: @AndrewT., right, i was not aware of that sister site of stack exchange actually. OK, I'll ask this same question at there too. Btw, will original low resolution version of image will have the same detail as resized version of bigger original image?

Comment: Personal opinion. Resizing original ones is better unless you need the picture for *nothing* other than uploading. With the original picture you can do various tweaks and save, but you can't "upscale" a small one.

Comment: Ok @iBug, I understand but what do you mean by various tweaks? Did it also include printing? I mean resized version of image will not give true output after printing but high resolution will certainly.